# Use QLoRA or alternative to fine tumne model loading some layers on GPU and some on CPU

Tags: python, pytorch, large-language-model

I can run a model on the GPU without getting OOM because I load 20 layers on GPU and 30 on CPU.
I can fine tune some LLM models using QLoRA https://github.com/georgesung/llm_qlora but if I try to fine tune this model I'm getting OOM.
Is it possible to load part of the model on GPU and part on the CPU while fine tunning the same way I do it when I load it?